# Error when trying to instantiate a new Message Object in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

### Problem

I am trying to create a [message object][1] in [discordjs][1] in order to send a message from my account. When I do this, I always get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

### Code

Here is my code:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author && message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    const myMessage = new Discord.Message(
      client,
      { author: { id: "myID" }, content: "My new Message" },
      message.channel
    );

    console.log(myMessage);
```

### Additional Information

I have logged Discord, client and message, all exist and are valid objects. I also replaced the data part of the constructor with this:

```
{ author: message.author, content: message.content },
```

but to no avail. The error was the same. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

### **Solution**

After hacking the source code of *discord.js* I discovered the culprit in the *Message.js* file. It is this line:

```
this.createdTimestamp = SnowflakeUtil.deconstruct(this.id).timestamp;
```

The problem is that I never passed any `id` to the constructor function in my `data` object. Just passing a fake id (a *string* of random numbers) did the trick.